# Is it possible to deploy ASP.NET Membership provider to Azure SQL Database for use with Azure Website MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I realise that this question has been asked a number of question, and the general feeling is to migrate to universal provider. However I am desperately trying to keep my code the same for hosting.

It is mvc3/.net4/EF4.1/SQL Server 2008 sp2.

So it is possible to migrate and use the Membership provider in the Azure "SQL Database" and Azure "Website" environment. I did try migrating the Membership tables using SQLAzureMW, but got user and role create errors, in addtion to "hints" being depracated.

Is there a way to port membership provider to Azure Websites.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For the benefit of all:

The answer I used was :

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2006191

You can use the old Membership providers, but with a tweaked Script as above.

Also I recommend the current version of MS's SSDT for schema and data comparison. Really useful tool for syncing DB to and from Azure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This script is no longer available

Comment: Does anyone have these scripts or know where they can be found?